# Given non-zero vectors $x$, $y$ in $R_n$, let $x\otimes y$ be the $n \times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $x_iy_j$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am so unsure on where to even start at for these problems.

The first part is:

Given non-zero vectors $x$, $y$ in $R_n$, let $x\otimes y$ be the $n \times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $x_iy_j$. Find the dimension of the range of $x \otimes y$. Enter your answer when $n=21$.

Then (the second part) is asking: (Continuing from the first problem) In addition, $x, y$ are linearly independent. Let $A=x\otimes y + y\otimes x$ Find the dimension of the kernel of $A$. Enter your answer when $n=21$.

Comment: If you have literally no idea on where to start, start with a few examples, maybe in dimension 2, 3, 4...

Comment: Great advice! I actually started this problem. I ended up getting one, but I keep on thinking I am taking a wrong approach to this problem. Part of me is debating on whether or not I truly understand the concept behind this problem. I only post a question if this is truly my last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining $x$ as column $n\times 1$ matrix and $y$ as a row $1\times n$ matrix, the product $x\otimes y$ is simply the matrix product $xy$:
$$
x\otimes y=xy=\begin{bmatrix}xy_1 &xy_2 & \cdots & xy_n     \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Notice that *each* column of this matrix is a multiple of $x$, then the dimension of the column space - the dimension of the matrix range, also known as the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) - is 1.

Another way to see this is recalling that the sum of the dimensions of the kernel and range for a matrix acting on a vector space is equal to the dimension of the vector space, what is called the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem). The kernel of $xy$ is the space formed for all vectors orthogonal to $y$. If $y$ is nonzero and the vector space has dimension $n$, then the kernel has dimension $n-1$ and the range has dimension 1.

For the second part what you have is $A=xy+y^Tx^T$. As $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, the kernel is the space formed by all vectors orthogonal to $x$ and $y$ simultaneously, a $(n-2)$-dimensional space.

Comment: So the first part is 1 (which is what I got for the first part), and the second part is n-2 (so 1-2, which is -1)? I was thinking it was 0 the whole time, because I was thinking of n-1. Your answer makes complete sense to me, and I think I might be understanding this more. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Answer to first part: 1 (the dimension for the column space). To second part: 21 - 2 = 19 (the *kernel* dimension).